# openshift . A gear restart did not complete on 1 gear

Tags: openshift

I get this kind error on my openshift acc

> A gear restart did not complete on 1 gear. Please try again and
>   contact support if the issue persists.

and yes i try restart from console, and from SSH and still not working.

so whats happen on my openshift ?

actually the site still running. but when i see the haproxy status its something like this

> frontgear                                open
>
> gear-53169xxxxx0012b-papxx               down
>
> loca-gear                                up
>
> backend                                  up

Is there any suggestion on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try manually scaling down to remove that gear, then set it back to your regular settings.